# Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred (swift 4)

Tags: xcode, swift4

I want to make a substring extension for string , I tried below 2 ways but unsuccessful:

```
extension String
{
    func substringToFirstChar(of char: Character) -> String
    {
        let pos = self.range(of: String(char))
        let subString = self[..<pos?.lowerBound]   
        return String(subString)
    }
}
```

or

```
extension String
{
    func substringToFirstChar(of char: Character) -> String
    {
        let pos = self.index(of: char)
        let subString = self[..<pos]
        return String(subString)
    }
}
```

> xcode prompt error:  **Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred**  at the "**let subString = self[..**" line.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`range(of` / `index(of` returns an optional. You have to unwrap the optional in the range expression

```
extension String
{
    func substringToFirstChar(of char: Character) -> String?
    {
        guard let pos = self.range(of: String(char))?.lowerBound else { return nil }
        // or  guard let pos = self.index(of: char) else { return nil }
        let subString = self[..<pos]
        return String(subString)
    }
}
```

alternatively – to avoid the optional – return the unchanged string if there is no match

```
extension String
{
    func substringToFirstChar(of char: Character) -> String
    {
        guard let pos = self.range(of: String(char))?.lowerBound else { return self }
        // or  guard let pos = self.index(of: char) else { return self }
        let subString = self[..<pos]
        return String(subString)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that, if the character does not appear in the string, you should return the whole string, not nil.

Comment: @Haiyuan you should mark this as answered if it fixed your issue.